# Redirect from secure site to non-secure site with wildcard subdomain

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, subdomain, mod-rewrite

I have the following set up in apache2.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.|)mydomain\.com$
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.mydomain\.com [NC,R=302,L]
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.com:443
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%1/
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/www.mydomain.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.com.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%1/

    <Directory /var/www/html/%1>
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTPS_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have all the behavior/functionality I need, except I can not get the last rewrite rule I have created to work. My intention is to redirect any SSL users on a wildcard subdomain to port 80 automatically (because I don't have a wildcard ssl certificate and I don't want them to see an error/warning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My intention is to redirect any SSL users on a wildcard subdomain to port 80 automatically (because I don't have a wildcard ssl certificate and I don't want them to see an error/warning)

Any redirections are done **AFTER** the TLS connection was established. Thus it is not possible to redirect a user away from a domain where you don't have a certificate for, because the certificate is needed before you can redirect the user.